# Add the order total weight to WooCommerce new order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Is it possible to show the total weight for an order in the WooCommerce "New order" email notification (for admins)?

Answer (score 7):

Here is that custom function hooked in woocommerce_email_after_order_table action hook, that will show on "New order" email notification the total weight

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_after_order_table','show_total_weight', 10, 4);
function show_total_weight( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){

    if ( 'new_order' != $email->id ) return;

    $total_weight = 0;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $product_item ){
        $quantity = $product_item->get_quantity(); // get quantity
        $product = $product_item->get_product(); // get the WC_Product object
        $product_weight = $product->get_weight(); // get the product weight
        // Add the line item weight to the total weight calculation
        $total_weight += floatval( $product_weight * $quantity );
    }

    // Styles
    $style1 = 'style="width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-top:0;"';
    $style2 = '  style="text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;border-top:0;"';
    $style3 = ' style="text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;border-top:0;"';

    // Output
    echo "<table class='td' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='6' $style1><tr><th $style2>" . __( 'Total weight: ', 'woocommerce' ) . "</th><td $style3>" . $total_weight . " kg</td></tr></table>";
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This is code tested and works only in WooCommerce 3+.

You will get that (example screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to change this so the weight is included in the email that goes to the customer instead of the one that goes to admin, and using the cart weight instead of the weight held against the product? Can I use $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')?

Comment: @Lyall Change `if ( 'new_order' != $email->id ) return;` to `if ( 'new_order' == $email->id ) return;`

Comment: Thanks - I just found one of your other answers about finding the email ID and changing that got it working, I needed to use customer_processing_order for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can change it to use the $woocommerce->cart->cart_total weight (or $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight) instead or the stored product weight? Thanks

Comment: `global $woocommerce` and `$woocommerce->cart`  are outdated… Use `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight()`… see it on [`WC_Cart `Class available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_contents_weight)