# Convert the order total weight in tons to WooCommerce new order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I'm using *¨[Add the order total weight to WooCommerce new order email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701473/add-the-order-total-weight-to-woocommerce-new-order-email-notification/45703269#45703269)¨* answer code to display the weight at the bottom of my emails added to my functions.php.

The code works fine, **but I need the conversion to be in tons** instead of lbs.

Comment: $total_weight = $total_weight*0.0005;

Comment: @mujuonly I'd add that in the total_weight area before the += or remove the whole floatval thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function show_total_weight( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    if ( 'new_order' != $email->id )
        return;

    $total_weight = 0;

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $product_item ) {
        $quantity        = $product_item->get_quantity(); // get quantity
        $product         = $product_item->get_product(); // get the WC_Product object
        $product_weight  = $product->get_weight(); // get the product weight
        // Add the line item weight to the total weight calculation
        $total_weight    += floatval( $product_weight * $quantity );
    }

    $total_weight = $total_weight * 0.0005;
    // Styles
    $style1  = 'style="width: 100%; font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; border-top:0;"';
    $style2  = '  style="text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;border-top:0;"';
    $style3  = ' style="text-align: left; border-top-width: 4px; color: #737373; border: 1px solid #e4e4e4; padding: 12px;border-top:0;"';

    // Output
    echo "<table class='td' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='6' $style1><tr><th $style2>" . __( 'Total weight: ', 'woocommerce' ) . "</th><td $style3>" . $total_weight . " kg</td></tr></table>";
}
```